# Registering a Javascript to be loaded on edit view

Tags: javascript, plone

What is the recommended way to register a Javascript to be loaded on the edit view (Archetypes) of certain content types?

- Javascript would be merged and compressed if it's portal_javascripts
- Creating portal_javascript condition is a problem: how to create a condition line checking for edit views of a certain content types and so that the line doesn't look like the leftovers of fighting crows
- Archetypes widgets support old fashioned way to dump files directly to  using macro slot fill

Any examples of existing implementations?

Comment: I just wanted to add: while there are answers to this question, none of them are ideal. We really need a much more general solution going forward, one that will deal with dependencies and will minimize points of injection.

Comment: @SteveM, what do you mean by "deal with dependencies"?

Comment: @SteveM I don't agree; from a site performance and cache-ability POV you want to minimize the number of Javascript files to load at all times. Thus, it's best to just load all JS together regardless of exactly what pages need them.

Comment: I'm thinking of something like zc.resourcelibrary or fantastic http://fanstatic.org/. But, Martijn's point is a really good one. The gotcha is that some of these javascript libraries are truly huge and may only be needed on a few pages -- or for editing a few pages.

Answer (score 6):

1. Make sure your JavaScript code works OK in those content type edit forms and doesn't break on other situations (jQuery is your friend). Then add it to portal_javascripts.
2. If you can associate the JavaScript to certain widgets, add it as `helper_js` for those widgets. Be careful with JavaScript as browser resources because I had trouble with `'++resoure++'-like` URLs as `helper_js`: apparently Archetypes doesn't like the plus (+) sign (doesn't escape plus sign correctly if I understand it OK).
3. You can define a page template named `archetypes_custom_js` with a macro called `javascript_head` and it will automatically be loaded in edit form of all Archetypes. You can then check special conditions in that macro. See [`base_edit.cpt`](http://svn.plone.org/svn/archetypes/Products.Archetypes/trunk/Products/Archetypes/skins/archetypes/base_edit.cpt) line 47.

Comment: svn is sooooo 2011.  https://github.com/plone/Products.Archetypes/blob/5e7d7f71379340d3ff2d5dcfea10d5519bb1f0a2/Products/Archetypes/skins/archetypes/base_edit.cpt#L47

Comment: Thanks FlipMcF, yes it was in the time I placed this answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

To be honest is such cases I like the approach that use old fill-slot directly in the edit form of the type.
The edit form is often not-so-frequently called (and for sure not from anonymous) so a little overhead due to downloading not-fully cached code is not so bad.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to have your javascript merged with as many other scripts as possible. Just load it either without a condition or only for authenticated users. All javascript code pertaining to editing included in Plone already loads for all authenticated users regardless.

Comment: I especially asked how to load for a particuar edit view. Unfortunately the javascripts are so heavy (jQuery UI) that merging them to every load would not make sense.